# How can I install texlive-science?

Tags: dependencies, texlive

For my Latex file I need to use the `algorithm2e` package, therefore I tried to install `texlive-science` for my Ubuntu. But in Ubuntu Software Center it says that *Dependency is not satisfiable: texlive-base(>=2018.20180416)*

I am not familiar with terminal and I always install packages via the Ubuntu Software Center. But this time I am faced with this dependency error, and will appreciate any help.

After trying `sudo apt install texlive texlive-full imagemagick`, I get:

```
texlive : Bağımlılıklar: texlive-latex-base (>= 2015) ama kurulmayacak
       Bağımlılıklar: texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2015) ama kurulmayacak
       Bağımlılıklar: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2015) ama kurulmayacak
texlive-full : Bağımlılıklar: texlive-humanities (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-swedish (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-humanities-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-es (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-en (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-fonts-extra (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-french (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-tibetan (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-ja (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-cs+sk (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-czechslovak (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-games (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-ukenglish (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-th (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-base (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-fi (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-pstricks-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-math-extra (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-science-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-generic-extra (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-latex3 (>= 2009-1)
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-hebrew (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-bg (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-formats-extra (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-finnish (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-plain-extra (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-de (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-pictures (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-polish (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: latex-xcolor (>= 2.09-1)
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-pt (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-mn (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-latex-extra-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-pstricks (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-base (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-latex-recommended-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-it (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-cyrillic (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-metapost (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-vietnamese (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-croatian (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-generic-recommended (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-other (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-metapost-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-arabic (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-latvian (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-si (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-african (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-german (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-latex-base-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: feynmf ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-latex-extra (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-tr (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: pgf (>= 1.01.dfsg.1-1)
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-greek (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: latexmk ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-spanish (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-font-utils (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: fragmaster ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-zh (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-ru (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: cm-super (>= 0.3.3-3) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-uk (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-lithuanian (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-armenian (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-fr (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-norwegian (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-music (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-portuguese (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-pl (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-publishers-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-nl (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-vi (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-indic (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-science (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-xetex (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-latex-base (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-publishers (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-bibtex-extra (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-latin (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-luatex (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-fonts-extra-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-danish (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-pictures-doc (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: context ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: latex-beamer (>= 3.06.dfsg.1-0.1)
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-italian (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-dutch (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-common (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-doc-ko (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-hungarian (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-extra-utils (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-omega (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Bağımlılıklar: texlive-lang-mongolian (>= 2009-1) ama kurulmayacak
            Tavsiye ettikleri: latex-cjk-all (>= 4.6.0+cvs20060714-2) ama kurulmayacak
```

Although it is not in english, I think it won't be a big problem for the people who are familiar with this kind of dependency problems.

Result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 (20151021)]/ wily main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-security universe
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily restricted multiverse
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-security restricted multiverse
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-updates restricted multiverse
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-proposed main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu/ wily-backports restricted multiverse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install LaTeX in Ubuntu 18.04 having `main`, `universe`, `restricted` and `multiverse` repositories enabled using the following command:

```
sudo apt install texlive texlive-full imagemagick
```

If the error hasn't gone, try

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive*
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And finally

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

**ADDENDUM**

Create copy of your sources.list file:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

**Only once(!!!)** run command (be careful during copiyng!!!)

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?ftp.linux.org.tr|archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Run command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install texlive-full and imagemagick packages:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full imagemagick
```

Comment: Thanks but I am using Ubuntu 15.10, and after running that command in terminal, I get a lot of dependency errors.

Comment: I have edited my question with the errors.

Comment: Oops, after trying these I cannot use `pdflatex` command. It says `bash: /usr/bin/pdflatex: No such file or directory`

Comment: No, it gave dependencies again.

Comment: added my sources.list

Comment: @Wiking the question is offtopic because it's specific to an EOL release, and we do not support End of Life releases here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: That wasn't the point of my comment, it was simply to let you know we don't support EOL releases.  (And to be fair, people on EOL releases *always* need help, the policy hasn't changed here on Ask Ubuntu in years about how we treat questions that are *specific* to EOL releases; they are also 100% vulnerable to many of the big vulnerabilities since they don't get security updates anymore so they **really** should upgrade...)

Comment: I never said you had to delete your answer.